# Which gates are “pre computation” universal?

Tags: circuits, boolean-algebra, digital-circuits

In the following, by “functions” I will mean 2 input 1 output Boolean logic functions (for conciseness).

A function is called “universal” if by using it (sometimes multiple times, chained together), you can construct all 16 functions.

However this isn’t the whole picture. In some esoteric circuit computing models, you keep track of all input/output variables and their negations. This allows you to have circuit universality once you get an AND and an OR gate. How? Consider if I have a large circuit composed of many NAND gates.

Given an individual NAND gate

c = a NAND b

we have

c = !a OR !b
!c = a AND b

Using these substitutions throughout the circuit, we can compute the original function we were computing with NAND gates, using only OR and AND gates. (With O(num inputs) pre computation time)

However, for example, linear computing only give us XOR/NOT, and there doesn’t seem to be an easy way to do some pre computation in the same manner.

To give a formal definition: call the function g a “NOT pre-computation universal function” if it can construct all functions, given the inputs and their negations, and outputting the output and its negation.

Which functions are “NOT pre-computation universal”? Is there a name for this idea and it’s generalizations (such as when you provide all pairwise applications of some function f) in the literature?

To generalize this, we can say a function f is “g pre-computation universal” given some function g if by being given the two inputs a,b and g(a,b), all 2 input 2 output functions can be produced (with a third output of g(first output, second output) to allow the substitution like above)

Comment: AND,OR; AND,XOR; OR,XOR; AND,NOT; OR,NOT; NAND; NOR.

Comment: There are only 16 functions, and 256 pairs of functions, so you should be able to write a computer program to enumerate all of them and determine which pairs are universal and which are not.

Comment: Note it is not exactly “pairs”, as my substitutions only allow for using those as inputs to the circuit, but don’t allow for using them in the circuit. I know this is a small distinction, but it’s important

Comment: Anyway though I agree this is easy to enumerate and solve, I’m asking because it gets more tricky for generalizations (base 3 and higher, and for more inputs and outputs) so I figure this concept is probably studied in circuit theory but I’m having trouble finding the words academics use for it

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I don't understand why it isn't pairs.  I don't follow what you mean by "those".  Rather than asking "is there a name for X", it is usually better to ask what you want to know about X.  That way an answer might still teach you what you want to know even if X doesn't have a standard "name".

Comment: I described a procedure that allows you to transform a large circuit that uses NAND gates into one that uses only AND and OR gates, that only requires you to pre-compute each input's NOT, replace all lines with a line carrying itself and it's NOT, and NAND gates with ( !a OR !b,  a AND b). This even works if the circuit has cycles in parts of it, which was really suprising to me.

I was wondering if similar substitutions existed for other bases (not just binary), sizes of circuits, and if the tradeoffs in these substitutions were studied.